# How to retrieve a list of facebook pages with a given keyword using facebook graph apis?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, html, facebook-page

I want to get a list of facebook pages which has a given word in it's description or name. Is it possible to get it from existing facebook graph apis.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#search // be aware this is a very rudimentary search, and search results will be tailored to the individual user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is available
use this:

```
search?q=Your_keyword&type=page
```

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=search%3Fq%3DYour_keyword%26type%3Dpage&version=v2.10#

for more options go here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#search

you can also extend as many options you need like this:

```
search?q=Your_keyword&type=page&fields=id,name,location
```